# Restore partition file after deleting the other files

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a date based partitioned database table like this

```
archivedmsgs#p#p202001.ibd
archivedmsgs#p#p202002.ibd
archivedmsgs#p#p202003.ibd
.
.
archivedmsgs#p#p202012.ibd
archivedmsgs#p#p2021.ibd
```

the 2020 partition files got deleted only archivedmsgs#p#p2021.ibd left how can I restore it's data

Comment: When a `.ibd` is deleted from the filesystem, the only hope involves having a backup.

Comment: I don't want to restore the deleted files, only archivedmsgs#p#p2021.ibd left and I need it's data but when I try to access the table I get "table doesn't exist in engine" error

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?  "When you try to use the *table* `archivedmsgs`, it claims to be missing?"  Apparently, that is the message you get even when one partition is missing.

There *may* be a cure.

Create a similar table with a the same schema and same partitioning.  That will create a file called `archivedmsgs#p#p2021.ibd`.  Move that into place.

Do that in a different `DATABASE` so that the table (and file) name can be the same without conflicting.

Comment: If this answer does not work, move the Question to dba.stackexchange.com ; there are more people with suitable knowledge of MySQL there.